# Permutations through different points

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm watching [Next (2007)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0435705/) and I'm trying to figure out a formula. The premise of the movie is that the protagonist can look into the future for two minutes and he is able to use this to alter his future. I'm trying to figure out the maximum number of permutations that he needs to resolve to get to an outcome.

I've made the following assumptions:

- The granularity is on Planck time scale, so the number of points is 120 × 1 / (5.39106(32) × 10−44);
- He can choose to make a decision at any point in time;
- He can choose to stop making decisions at any time.

So, there are two parts to this. The first formula I was looking for is the number of permutations for an x number of points. The values should be something like this:

1. No choice, so 0;
2. Also no choice because there is a single path, so 0;
3. 2:

   1. A through B to C;
   2. A directly to C;
4. 4:

   1. A through B and C to D;
   2. A through B to D;
   3. A through C to D;
   4. A directly to D;

Etc.

The second part is executing this formula over the range from 1 to 120 × 1 / (5.39106(32) × 10−44), because he can choose to stop making a choice at any time.

Comment: Purmutations sounds like group theory for when Sheldon is sick...

Comment: Another way to formulate your first problem is probably more familiar to people: "How many ways can I write a sequence of $N$ integers with endpoints $1$ & $N$, if my sequence never decreases?" (I suspect that's shown up on MSE before.)

Comment: Shouldn't there be one choice for case x = 2?

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think so. There is no choice to make at A because the only destination is B. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Considering $N$ points, we can go from the first to the last point passing through $k$ ($k=0,1,2....N-2$) of the remaining points. Assuming that "coming back" in the direction the first point is not allowed during the path (as the OP seems to suggest), we have $N-2\choose 0$ possible paths passing through none of these points, $N-2 \choose 1$ possible paths passing through one of these points, $N-2 \choose 2$ possible paths passing through two of these points, and so on. Generalizing, we get $N-2 \choose k$ possible paths passing through $k$ of these points. The total number of paths for a given value of $N$ is therefore given by the sum of all binomial coefficients for $N-2$, which is $2^{N-2}$. This formula can be directly applied to the number $120/ t_p$, where $t_p$ is Planck time.

Comment: That the answer is as simple as $2^{N-2}$ suggests that there's some simpler way to count these paths. Would it just be that each path amounts to choosing which of the $N-2$ points that the traveller goes through?

Comment: I agree with you. We could achieve the same result by considering that each of the $N-2$ points can be included or not included in the path. This may directly lead to the solution $2^{N-2}$.

Comment: Terrific. However, if I'm correct, this is only half the answer. That he can choose to influence the future at any point also influences the formula and if I'm correct, this means that this formula needs to be executed over the range 2..$120/t_p$. How do you do that? On a side note. I don't have Matlab and everything I try to enter this formula in to gives `Inf` as a result, including [online Matlabs](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_matlab_online.php). Is it possible that you also calculate the result?

Comment: It depends on what we are looking for. At any time of his life, the protagonist can look ahead and see all possibilities included in the next two minutes. If we restrict our analysis to a single moment of his life and the following two minutes, the number of possibilities progressively decreases over this interval, choice after choice, and becomes zero at the end of the two minutes. What exactly would you like to calculate?

Comment: I get that, but that still assumes that he is using the full two minutes. What if he said after one minute he's fine with the result. That would bring the number of choices down, but in itself would also be a choice. I'm trying to figure out a way to incorporate that into the calculation.

Comment: If he uses only part of the two minutes, calling $K$ the number of seconds used (with $K<120$), we get that the number of choices is $2^{K/t_p-2}$.